# Is it possible to return different values depending on the number of times a machine made a request to an asmx web server, if so how?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I am new to C# and Web Services so for better understanding I am gonna ask using an example. I have a WebService1.asmx.cs that can do 4 math operations with 2 given integers. Is it possible to use a number as an input and the second number as the times a machine used the web service? Using Visual Studio 2022 .NET Framework version 4.6.2 on Windows 11

**Example:**

```
from suds import Client
url="https://localhost:44337/WebService1.asmx?WSDL"
c = Client(url)
result = c.service.Add(2,3) 
print(result) 

#Output is 5
```

To

```
from suds import Client
url="https://localhost:44337/WebService1.asmx?WSDL"
c = Client(url)
result = c.service.Add(2) 
print(result) 

#In this case we make 1 request before this one so 2+1=3 and the next one will output 4 and so on.
```

Comment: Unless you store some sort of call count in your server-side - for example in a database table, you cannot know how many times a client called your web service.

Comment: I thought about that I was unable to identify different users

Comment: If you do not have authentication to identify the user, then it will be difficult. You could keep the count as per the "client IP" present as part of http request, but that will not be exact , because multiple systems can reach to your webservice via a Proxy server.

Comment: I think I am gonna go with IPv6 address thank you!